# Model Formset and regular ModelForm in same template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, inline-formset

I got two models:

`Project:`

```
class Project(Model):
    
    name = CharField(max_length=50)
    members = ManyToManyField("accounts.User", through='ProjectUser')
    organization = ForeignKey(Organization, related_name="projects", on_delete=CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and `Task:`

```
class Task(Model):
    task = CharField(max_length=100)
    project = ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'task'
```

I got a `UpdateView` class:

```
class ProjectUpdateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = ProjectUpdateForm
    template_name = 'projects/project_edit.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('projects:list')
```

How can I allow a user to add tasks (through an inline formset) on the same page as where they'd edit a `Project` instance?

E.g one consolidated form where the user can edit the `Project name`, and add / remove `Task` instances, all in one place

Answer (score 0):

**Form/Formset:**

First, create a form and a formset for your Task model

```
class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['task']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)



class TaskBaseFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TaskBaseFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)



TaskFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Project,  # parent_model
    Task,  # model
    form=TaskForm, 
    formset=TaskBaseFormSet
)
```

Or maybe all that you need to do to create a TaskFormset if you dont need a TaskForm class is this

```
TaskFormset = inlineformset_factory(Project, Task, fields=('task',))
```

**View:**

I see you're using a UpdateView class for your view, so you can do this to get a TaskFormset in your context_data, so now you can use the TaskFormset in the template that you declared in the 'template_name' property of your UpdateView class

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    if self.request.POST:
        context['task_formset'] = forms.TaskFormset(self.request.POST)
    else:
        context['task_formset'] = forms.TaskFormset()


    return context

# In the form_valid method of your UpdateView class you can validate the data 
# and assign the Project instance to all the tasks that were create by the formsets

def form_valid(self, form):

     task_formset = context['task_formset']

     # you can validate formset data like this
     if not task_formset.is_valid():
        return self.form_invalid(form)


     project = form.save()
     # Here you assign the Project instance to the Tasks
     task_formset.instance = project
     task_formset.save()

     return super().form_valid(form)
```

**Template:**

Now all that you need to do is to print the management_form and each form from the formset using a loop as you can see in the code below

```
<form method="post">

    <!-- Your ProjectUpdateForm form here... -->

    {{ task_formset.management_form }}
    <table>
        {% for form in task_formset %}
        {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</form>
```

Hope this can help! There are some links to the official Django documentation that you may find useful:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/models/#inlineformset-factory